# How to check which collection a user's data is in? Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I search a user's email in a cloud firestore collection? I have 3 collections, in the login page I want to take the entered email and check it against the three collections I have in the cloud, once the email is found in one of the collection, it will navigate to a certain page depending on which collection the user's email is saved in.

The application is developed using flutter and dart.

The snippet bellow is in the login page when the button is pressed.

```
if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                _key.currentState.save();
                try {
                  final userlogin = FirebaseAuth.instance
                      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: _email, password: _password);
                } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                  switch (e.code) {
                    case 'invalid-email':
                     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid Email")));
                      break;
                    case 'user-disabled':
                     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text("Disabled!")));
                      break;
                    case 'user-not-found':
                     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text("User not found")));
                      break;
                    case 'wrong-password':
                     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text("Wrong password.")));
                      break;
                  }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very limited support for [search across multiple collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) in Firestore: all collections must have the same name.

If your collections don't all share the same name, you'll need a separate query for each collection. In that case I'd actually recommend changing your data structure to have a single collection for all users, and storing their role in each user's document in there.